Error Response from SOAP Webservice using CURL
I am facing an issue while calling a SOAP service that uses SOAP 1.2. The service works fine when called from SOAPUI. However, when making the same call from the same machine with the same XML request body, it shows an error.
Sample Request:
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a11="http://aaa.asdsad.com">
 <soap:Header>
  <a11:MHdr>
   <a11:name>test</a11:name>
  </a11:MHdr>
 </soap:Header>
 <soap:Body>
  <a11:Data>
   <a11:RQ>
   <a11:Cd>1</a11:Cd>
  </a11:RQ>
 </a11:Data>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Error Response from Provider End:

virtual service: NONE. Cause: Transport level information does not match with SOAP Message namespace URI

I am unsure of the reason, as the request and headers are the same in both CURL and SOAPUI.

Please provide any solution or suggestion...
